# Dynamically add label and textbox for each column in database and bind to gridcontrol selected row

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a form with one combobox which holds the names of tables in my database, by selecting any of tables my gridcontrol itemssource is set to that table and all records from that table are shown. 
What i need to do is, I need to add one label and one textbox for each of columns in selected table and bind the values to selected row in gridcontrol.

This piece of code gives me information about columns in selected table correctly:

```
       tabeleK3 = selectQuery("DESCRIBE " & comboBox.SelectedItem("TABLE_NAME"))
    For Each row As DataRow In tabeleK3.Rows
        Console.WriteLine(row.Item("Field") & " - " & row.Item("Type"))
    Next row
```

This is the output for one of my tables:

```
ip - varchar(15)
timestamp - int(11) unsigned
knt - varchar(7)
tip - int(11)
tem - int(11)
```

For these 5 columns i need to add textbox and label(name of the column). Textbox should be bound to gridcontrol, this is gridcontrol code:

```
      tabeleK2 = selectQuery("select * from " & comboBox.SelectedItem("TABLE_NAME"))
      gridData.ItemsSource = tabeleK2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [DataGridTemplateColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn?view=netframework-4.7.2) to the `DataGrid` in your XAML markup:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridData">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="label..." />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding YourField}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```